# Dynamically Load items from Store to Controller

Tags: javascript, google-maps, extjs, sencha-touch-2

How can i load my store dynamically into my controller so as to be able to load the lat and log on the map once any of the item in the list is taped.

```
listeners: {
            maprender: function(component, map, geo, eOpts) {
                var position = new google.maps.LatLng(5.978132,116.072617);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map
                        });

                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: 'Working Fine'
                        });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        });

            setTimeout(function() {
                    map.panTo(position);
                }, 1000);

                },
           },
```

The code above works but it only locates one particular location for all the items in the list reason being that the lat and log is static. I want to make it load the lat and log dynamically from my store.

My Store:

```
Ext.define('List.store.Presidents', {
extend : 'Ext.data.Store',

config : {
model : 'List.model.President',
sorters : 'lastName',
storeId: 'contactmap',
grouper : function(record) {
    return record.get('lastName')[0];
},

data : [{
    firstName : "Ikhlas HQ",
    lastName : "Tower 11A, Avenue 5, Bangsar South, No.8 Jalan Kerinchi 59200 Kuala Lumpur",
    lat : 3.110649,
    lng : 101.664991,
    id: '200',
},
{
    firstName : "PEJABAT WILAYAH SELANGOR",
    lastName : "No. 97, 97-1 & 97-2, Jalan Mahogani 5/KS7, Ambang Botanic, 41200 Klang, Selangor",
    lat : 3.003384,
    log : 101.45256,
    id: '001',
},]}
});
```

My Controller:

```
Ext.define('List.controller.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
config: {
refs: {
    main: 'mainpanel',
  },
control: {
    myList: {
        itemtap: 'onMyListItemTap'
    },
    'presidentlist': {
            disclose: 'showDetail'
        },
 }
},
showDetail: function(list, record) {
            this.getMain().push({
                xtype: 'presidentdetail',
                title: record.fullName(),

onMyListItemTap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts) {
```

// some functionality needs to be here to load my store 
    }
    });
    },
    });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways you can do it...

```
list.getStore();
```

should return the store thats associated with the list.

But, the onMyListItemTap function returns the "record" as part of its arguments, so you could just do:

```
var lat = record.get('lat'),
    long = record.get('long');
```